# 400 Bad Request - while POSTing JSON data to RESTful controller implemented with Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to POST some JSON data to RESTful spring controller. But getting "400 Bad Request" as response status.

Giving below code from the key configuration files which I am using for this:

**pom.xml dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lokur.controllers" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="xml" value="text/xml" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Controller class:**

```
package com.lokur.controllers;

import com.lokur.dto.Employee;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee, HttpServletResponse response) {

        System.out.println("Saving employee...");
        System.out.println("Emp ID = " + employee.getId());
        System.out.println("Emp Name = " + employee.getName());

        // Set dummy "location" for this newly created Employee resource in response header
        response.setHeader("Location", "/employees/"+employee.getId());
    }

}
```

**Request details:**

*URL:* http: //localhost:8081/RestfulWSPOC/employees

*Method:* POST

*Headers:* Accept: application/json

*Payload:*

```
{
    id: 300999

    name: "Akshay Lokur"

    designation: "Associate"

    department: "Tech"

    salary: 500000
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show the Employee class as well, and also any possible stacktrace that you are seeing?

Comment: @geoand: Issue resolved. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the issue:

The problem was mere syntax issue with my JSON request (had missed commas!).

I corrected it like below and it is working like a charm now:

```
{
    "id": 300999,
    "name": "Akshay Lokur",
    "designation": "Associate",
    "department": "Tech",
    "salary": 500000
}
```

Response:

```
201 Created
```

P.S.: We also need to give double quotes to "keys" in JSON!

Yippee :)

Cheers.